# Show that P is equidistant from B and C.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

P is drawn using the exterior angle bisector of A.
[image]

Comment: Is BC supposed to be a diameter so $\alpha$ should be a right angle ?

Comment: No, triangle ABC is just an arbitrary triangle with circumcircle O. They just happen to line up like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $\theta=\frac \alpha 2$ and extend $PA$

$$\angle PAB = \theta \text{ (  Opposite angles at A)}$$ 
$$\angle PCB =\angle PAB = \theta \text{ (  both subtend PB )}$$

Let $x=\angle APC$ and $y=\angle ACP$

Then

$$x+y=\theta \text{ (  exterior angle in  }\triangle APC  \;) $$

$$\angle APC=\angle ABC = x \text{ (  both subtend AC )}$$

$$\angle ACP=\angle ABP = y \text{ (  both subtend AP )}$$

$$\angle PBC =\angle PBA+\angle ABC = x+y=\theta$$

So $\triangle PBC$ is isosceles ( $\angle PBC= \angle PCB=\theta$ )